# Create a StartDate and EndDate column after value change using either T-SQL, DAX or M Query

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table as follows:

Date /  Name  / OldValue  / NewValue

I want a way to create a Start Date & End Date columns using any of the following : DAX , T-SQL or M Query.

Meaning; the StartDate is the [Date] and the End the date is the Date where the same person will change value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

Comment: I made the changes @DaleK

Comment: It didn't work for me @Charlieface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Power Query M, you can follow these steps:

- In my demo data the columns came in sorted correctly, but you can use this code to ensure they are:

  `#"Sort Table" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}})`
- Add an Index column > Add Column > Index Column > From 0 (It HAS to be from 0)
- Add Column > Custom Column > name End Date >

  `if [Name] <> #"Added Index" [Name] {[Index] + 1} then null else Date.AddDays(#"Added Index" [Date] {[Index] + 1},-1)`
- Right-click End Date > Replace Errors > Replace with null
- Adjust column order as needed
- Rename New Value column to "Value", rename Date column to "Start Date".  Remove unneeded columns

Source and Output:
[image]

EDIT: I should add that this works okay on a small data set, but on a larger one you may run into performance issues.  In that case you should duplicate the query, add an index starting at 0 for one query, and on the other query start an index at 1.  Then you can merge the two together to extract the necessary dates and values.

Comment: I did run into performance issues. But how will duplicating the query solve it ? it'll just be doing the same thing twice !